# To download a CSV file, is any code like JSR223 / BeanShell PostProcessor required or just 'Save Responses to a file' listener is sufficient?

Tags: jmeter

I have a POST request to download a .CSV file from the search results of a web page. I added a 'Save response to a file' listener along with my POST request. I can see the contents of the file in the response body in the view Results tree but I am not able to see the downloaded file in the path I specified. If I dont specify any path, the file is expected to be downloaded into JMeter's bin directory location as default - correct? Please could someone give an example explaining if I need to mention the file name with full path starting with ~/... for mac book or only the directory name is enough?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Here is the setup to store the file as `file.csv` under "bin" folder of your JMeter installation (or in JMeter's [working directory](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/services/FileServer.html#getDefaultBase--) if it differs from "bin")

You can also use [absolute paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths) like:

```
/Users/your-user/here/somefolder/file.csv
```

or relative paths like:

```
../file.csv
```

this way the file will be stored one folder above JMeter's "bin" folder (again if JMeter's working directory is different the file will be stored one level above)

More information: [Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter)